# Массив из 8 элементов раскидать в 16 элементов

Tags: swift

Есть массив из 8 элементов как его разбросать в массив из 16 элементов в случайном порядке. должно быть все попарно. даже не представляю как это зделать

UPD!

есть массив например

```
var hiddenNodes = [String]() 

var pairNodes = ["Star","Rectangle","Square","Plus","Minus","Triangle","Circle","Romb"]

// разбрасываем по парно в массив получается 16 элементов для сравнения
```

Comment: можете привести пример, что должно получить в результате?

Comment: есть например 8 картинок, которые должны сравниваться между собой например у меня есть 16 квадратов. Нужно найти все пары картинок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pairNodes = ["Star","Rectangle","Square","Plus","Minus","Triangle","Circle","Romb"]
pairNodes += pairNodes

var shuffledNodes:[String] = []

for var i = pairNodes.count; i > 0; i-- {
let randomElement = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i)))
    shuffledNodes.append(pairNodes[randomElement])
    pairNodes.removeAtIndex(randomElement)    
}
print(shuffledNodes)
```

Comment: спасибо, хорошая работа